# Is it possible to have a program load on startup, but before user login?

Tags: windows-8, boot

I want to have my magicJack load every time the computer reboots whether a user is logged in or not.

I currently am able to do this by enabling automatic logins and having the program in the startup folder.  I think that this used to be something you'd configure a service for, but as I recall this forced the program to run in the background and made the HMI inaccessible.

Comment: What is it you want/expect the MagicJack software to be able to do for you while not logged on?  I ask because it probably won't have any access to things like the sound and such, unless there's a user actually logged in.  Have you tried a [basic Windows Task](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6cde20/create-schedule-task-in-windows-8/) with a trigger of "When the computer starts"?  What have you tried already?

Comment: @techie007 As stated, I am presently doing it by startup folder and using a login without password to bring it up.  I don't expect the hmi to be present until a user logs in, of course, but I also don't want to have to twice load the software.  I'm looking for the functionality of running my phone when at the user prompt, but the full hmi when a user logs in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sugestion would be to use gpedit.msc (remember the msc)
In particular, use the Computer (not user) Settings
Windows Settings
Startup

Put your commands here to start magic jack.

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy. Take a look in [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192). You will find there a detailed Microsoft guide how to make a service by yourself to make programs start after boot without user logged on.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable) you have a similar question with accepted answer.

command itself:

```
sc create newservice binpath= <pat_to_the_executable>
```

Comment: From the question ... `I think that this used to be something you'd configure a service for, but as I recall this forced the program to run in the background and made the HMI inaccessible.`